# Can you connect multiple UVC cameras to a single USB3 port?

Tags: usb, webcam, usb-3

I have 2 VGA at 120 fps cameras and one 2560x720 at 60 fps UVC camera sending MJPEG streams.
I think a single USB3 port should be handle the bandwith but is it supported to connect several to one port, say via USB hub?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the limitations have been changed for USB 3.0 but USB 2.0 allows up to 127 devices per root controller. One USB port on your computer is likely not to be equal to one root controller as a computer usually already has an internal hub to have multiple ports per root controller.

Each hub you connect to your root controller is subtracted from the total number of devices that can be connected to a root controller. So let's say you use 3 hubs then the maximum number of devices is 127 - 3 = 124.

Additionally, you can only connect up to 5 hubs in one chain. This is sometimes difficult to count as hubs with many ports might have more than one USB hub inside.

To answer your question: using an appropriate hub (i.e. one that can power your devices if they don't have their own power supply) you should be able to connect three devices if you deem the bandwidth of USB 3.0 to be sufficient. Do note that there is always some overhead to the theoretical bandwidth of USB 3.0 so if it's going to be tight then it'll likely not work smoothly.